# Jquery hasClass for multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having,

```
<tr valign="top">
    <th class="chkCol fixed">..checkbox..</th>
    <th class="fixed">..head..</th>
</tr>
```

Now in Jquery I am calling a function like,

```
if($(this).hasClass("fixed")){
   ....
}
```

If I call `$(this).hasClass("fixed")`, then I need to get only head not checkbox and that is working perfect in Jquery 1.4.2 but now I updated to jquery 1.6.1.
Now I am getting checkbox inside if condition.

Please Help,

Thanks in advance

Comment: $(this).hasClass("fixed") will always return both the th elements even in the older version. You will have to filter the results

Comment: There's no way that worked differently in jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: Ok, this is the interesting part, this bug appears on Firefox 4. Working in IE :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>I'd be very surprised if jQuery 1.4.2 gets this wrong</s> jQuery 1.4.2 does not get this wrong. `hasClass("fixed")` should be true in both cases, in all versions of jQuery. [Here's an example](http://jsbin.com/oleta5) using v1.6.1, and [the same example](http://jsbin.com/oleta5/2) using v1.4.2. Both work fine.

If you want to check that "fixed" it's the **only** class on an element, that's more easily done without jQuery, by going directly to the reflected property:

```
if (this.className === "fixed") {
    // ...
}
```

`className` is a property reflecting the "class" attribute, and like the "class" attribute it's a space-delimited string.

The above will fail, of course, if the element has any other class on it as well, like "fixed something-else".

If you specifically want to check it has "fixed" and doesn't have "chkCol", then you have to do that on purpose:

```
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.hasClass("fixed") && !$this.hasClass("chkCol")) {
    // ...
}
```

If you were doing this in a selector (rather than checking an element you already had) you could use the selector `".fixed:not(.chkCol)"`. But although you *can* do that with an element you already have using [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), it's unnecessarily expensive (jQuery has to parse the selector).

---

**Update**: You've said that you've tried the `&& !$this.hasClass("chkCol")` thing and it hasn't worked. That means that something *earlier* in the `if` condition has already determined the outcome of the expression as a whole, and so the result of the `!$this.hasClass("chkCol")` part makes no difference (and isn't getting run at all, as JavaScript short-circuits expressions).

Example:

```
var x = 1;

if (x == 1 || $this.hasClass("fixed") && !$this.hasClass("chkCol"))
```

In that case, because `x` is `1`, nothing to the right of the `||` is even looked at at all; the expression's value is already `true`.

---

**Update 2**:

You've said you're using `hasClass`, but in a comment on another answer you said:

> If i use `$(this).attr('class') == "fixed"`, then not at all going into if condition

I don't suppose what you're actually doing is this:

```
if ($(this).attr('className') == "fixed") {
    // ...
}
```

Note that's "className", not "class". If that's what you're doing, that **will not work** on 1.6.1 but it will on 1.4.2. There is no *attribute* called "className"; there's an attribute called "class" and a *property* called "className". jQuery 1.6.x differentiates between attributes and properties.

My code above, using `hasClass`, will work on all versions. Or change your code to use `attr("class")` rather than `attr("className")`.

[Here's a v1.4.2 example](http://jsbin.com/ugefu4/3) showing `attr("className")` working (which it shouldn't). [Here's a v1.6.1 example](http://jsbin.com/ugefu4/2) showing `attr("className")` not working (which is correct). Both versions show the correct way to get at the "class" attribute.

Comment: @Max: It's nothing to do with `hasClass`. It's something else in your code. I've speculated on what it might be in an update above.

Comment: ok, My Bad, I am checking for the whole object instead of inside 'th'. This thing worked, thanks buddy

Comment: @Max: Good deal, glad that helped.

Answer (score 3):

You could either do this:

```
if ($(this).attr('className') === 'fixed')
```

or else:

```
if ($(this).not('.chkCol').hasClass('fixed'))
```

I think it'd be better to make sure that "chkCol" elements never get the "fixed" class in the first place.

*edit* — the ever-perceptive @T. J. Crowder points out correctly that ".attr()" is, as of jQuery 1.6, the wrong way to get property values from elements. There's a degree of angelic pin dancing involved in the explanation of why that's the case, but suffice to say that you'd now use:

```
if ($(this).prop('className') === 'fixed')
```

Comment: Note that `attr('className')` won't work on v1.6.1, because "className" is not an attribute and 1.6.x is more strict about that. Just use `this.className`, or `$(this).attr('class')` if you really want to do all that work. :-)

Comment: @TJ I haven't upgraded yet :-)  It's on my plan for this week, so I'm sure I'll find a bunch of this (though I never do anything like grab the class string like that) (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the update has fixed a bug, then :) `hasClass("fixed")` should definetely be true for both `th` elements here.

As for your problem, either explicitly exclude `chkCol` class:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("fixed") && !$(this).hasClass("chkCol")) {
```

or find some other criteria identifying the element you are looking for (tag name, ID, another dedicated class, etc.).

Comment: +1 for faster typing... I would say that this was a bug in 1.4.2

Comment: I observed !(not) is not recognized by 1.6.1

Comment: @Max: I'm sorry, but jQuery does not get this wrong. The problem lies elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Well, the `!` is a feature of JS itself so it'll work regardless of your jQuery version :)

Comment: I agree. but when i tried with !$(this).hasClass("chkCol") alone, still going into if condition

Comment: @Max: Then a previous criterion in the `if` statement is true and you've used `||` or similar, so the expression as a whole is true even though the part you're checking is not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, then it must have been a bug in jQuery 1.4.2 because obviously the `<th class="chkCol fixed">..checkbox..</th>` has the class "fixed".

If you want to get a element with the only class "fixed" you could do

```
($(this).attr('class') == "fixed")
```

Comment: this is object. If i use $(this).attr('class') == "fixed", then not at all going into if condition

Comment: `$(this)` is always an object. Here it has to be a jQuery object of `<th class="fixed">..head..</th>` to have that condition to work. In which context you use `$(this)`? an event listener?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use attr() instead:

```
if($(this).attr("class") == "fixed"){
   ....
}
```

Comment: that's what Daniel also suggested buddy